# Rails Models: Where does this object come from?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Following code:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
    validates :name, presence: true
    validates :price, numericality: { 
        greater_than_or_equal_to: 0.0 
    }
    validates :description, presence: true
 
    belongs_to :user
 
    def owned_by? owner
        user == owner # Where does the user-obj. come from?
    end
end
```

It works. What I don't get is: **Where does the "user"-object come from?** Please see the line with comment!

"user" is nowhere declared / assigned a value.

Does someone know how that works and can it explain to me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [`ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods#belongs_to`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to) API docs:

> Methods will be added for retrieval and query for a single associated
> object, for which this object holds an id:
>
> `association` is a placeholder for the symbol passed as the name
> argument, so belongs_to :author would add among others author.nil?.
>
> Example
>
> A Post class declares belongs_to :author, which will add:
>
> ```
> Post#author (similar to Author.find(author_id))
> ...
> ```

So in your case, after declaring the `belongs_to :user` relationship you get that bunch of methods, among them `user`.